# Can I normalize a gradient vector where each dimension has a different unit?

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, gradient-descent

Suppose I have a gradient vector
\begin{bmatrix}
       x_{1} \ \frac{cm}{s} \\
       x_{2}\ \frac{^{\circ}}{s} \\
     \end{bmatrix}
where $x_1$ is given in cm per second while $x_2$ is given in degrees per second. If I normalize this vector by dividing both elements by $\sqrt{x_1^2 +x_2^2}$, would it still point towards the maximum of the function?

Comment: A vector's components can't have different units. Something must have gone wrong in the gradient calculation.

Comment: These aren't exactly SI units, but the problem here is that when numerically calculating the gradient, I have to use $\Delta x_1 >> \Delta x_2$ for $\frac {f(x_0) - f (x_0 + \Delta x)}{\Delta x}$ and this skews the gradient

Comment: SI or not isn't the problem. Not being dimensionally consistent is the problem. What's the context in which this gradient is being calculated?

Comment: I'm trying to optimize a function with lots of different parameters but the range of the variables is very different. Some of them are between 0 and 0.1, while others are in the 1000-10000. So a $\Delta x$ of 0.001 in one dimension would change the result of the optimization function the same way as a difference of 100 in another dimension.